# Attaching file to new record in Visual Flow

Tags: visual-workflow

I am using Flows in my Community to allow users to upload records in the Case record detail page like below.

[image]

Uploading the [file in a flow](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=vpm_designer_elements_screen_fileupload.htm&type=5) to the Case is easy enough, however I would like to expand this so the file creates a new Audit__c record (which has a lookup to my Case) and attaches to this instead.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was able to achieve this in a slightly different way, instead of re-parenting the file to the new `Audit__c` record I simply created a new `ContentDocumentLink` and linked the file to the `Audit__c` record.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is create the Audit__c record before you attach the file in your upload screen: you can use a Record Create component for this, passing the Case Id from the community builder into the case lookup field on the Audit__c record.

Next, assign this Audit Record's Id to a variable.

Then, in your upload screen, assign the newly created Audit__c record Id as the Related Record Id in the file upload component.

The new Audit record will have the file you uploaded attached to it, and it will lookup to the case.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with above responses, but a slightly better way to do this is to attach the files to the User Record `{!$User.Id}` and then create the ContentDocumentLink records afterward. This way you don't have to create an extra audit__c record.